# Terminal doesn't recognize pip as a directory on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

While trying to troubleshoot why the `$ pip install` command always returns code 1 errors, I tried to enter my `pip` directory from within a shell.

I started by running

```
$ which pip
```

and got

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip

When I subsequently run

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/
```

and run `ls`, I get the following:

[image]

which clearly includes `'pip'` as a directory.

However, when I run

```
$ cd pip
```

I get the following error.

> bash: cd: pip: Not a directory

How is this possible?

Comment: Your screenshot does not show `pip` to clearly included as a directory... can you do a `ls -la` instead?

Comment: `pip` is not a directory indeed. Hence why its in `/bin/`. Its a exec binary.

Comment: In fact `pip` as python module **IS A** directory. Try `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`. What it gives you?

Comment: @Ingaz but in this case it would be found under `site-packets`, not `bin`, right? In this screenshot, it seems that pip is indeed an executable file.

Comment: @eulerspython try to run `cat pip` to ensure it is not a file.

Comment: @brandizzi Write `cat $(where pip)`. I think now it must be clear. (If you have `where`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip` is not a directory; it's an executable binary. You can only `cd` into a directory.

The command `$ which pip` returns the executable that would have been executed if `pip` had been entered at the shell prompt. Take a look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for `which`.